# How to disable a knob by a button click in jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable my knob by a button click. how can I make it possible. here is my html code

```
<div class="knob_control">
    <input id="bluegainControl" class="knob_control" 
           data-width="80"data-cursor=true data-fgColor="#00255B" data-thickness=.3 value="0">
</div>
```

This is the code I added in the button click. but it's not working

```
$("#bluegainControl").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: where is your button that you want to click?

Comment: you can just made it by your own.i forget to add that part of code

Comment: @ThanzeerSalim where is your attempt? Please note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: $("#bluegainControl").prop("disabled", "disabled"); this is what i added when the button click occurs.,but its not working. i dont know what should i do next

Comment: @ThanzeerSalim your code is working just fine, please include all relevant code, including the click event and the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly then try this, one button will disable the input and another will enable it.

Your code is working fine, it's not clear to me why your code isn't working for you as you didn't post your related code.

Use [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method to track your click event.

```js
$('#dBtnClk').click(function(){
        $('#bluegainControl').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#eBtnClk').click(function(){
        $('#bluegainControl').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="knob_control" id="knob_control"><input id="bluegainControl" class="knob_control" data-width="80"data-cursor=true data-fgColor="#00255B" data-thickness=.3 value="0"></div> 
<button id="dBtnClk">Disable Input</button>
<button id="eBtnClk">Enable Input</button>
```